Transmission probability under spatial symmetry
Consider a simple two-band tight-binding system given in momentum space $$H=f_1(k_x)\sigma_x+f_2(k_y)\sigma_y+f_3(k_x,k_y,k_z)\sigma_z$$ where $\sigma_{x,y,z}$ are Pauli matrices, say, for some orbitals. $f_{1},f_2$ are odd functions such as $\sin(k_i)$ while $f_3$ is even in all $k_x,k_y,k_z$.
Then we attach leads to this system as in the figure, apply a magnetic field $B\hat{y}$, and calculate the transmission probabilities $T_{ij}$ from $j$ to $i$, e.g., in the Landauer-Buttiker formalism.

It turns out that $$T_{01}(B)=T_{32}(-B)$$ always hold. How to see this from symmetry considerations?
(If necessary, let's assume the leads are in a geometrically symmetric configuration.)
My first thought is this might have something to do with mirror operation $M_x$, since $M_x:B\hat{y}\rightarrow -B\hat{y}$. Then if $M_x$ is a symmetry when $B=0$, we should have the relation above.
However, $H$ will have the sign of its first term reversed under $M_x$. So when $B=0$, $M_x$ seems to be not a symmetry although the band structure is invariant (since $f$'s will be squared).
